# vsftpd: use Explicit SSL in a different port than unencrypted FTP

Tags: ftp, ssl, vsftpd, ftps

I've managed to run vsftpd with unencrypted FTP, Implicit SSL, and Explicit SSL. What I'm looking for is a way to run it with Explicit SSL, but have a separate port for SSL.

For example: port 15000 for unencrypted, and port 15001 for SSL.

This is because I want to enable LAN users to connect unencrypted but WAN users to connect *only* encrypted.

I would use SSL on LAN too, but I'll be going Gigabit soon (laggard) and having a couple of users transfer files at speeds 70-100MB/sec is going to bring my server's CPU to its knees.

What has worked so far is to run two instances of vsftpd with different configs. I was hoping for a more tidy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to [this question at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/611361/how-do-you-setup-multiple-instances-of-vsftpd-to-run-on-different-listen-ports) suggest the only way to do this is to run two separate instances of vsftpd, each with one of the configurations you want.

Comment: I had a feeling that this would be the answer. I created a second init script for the second instance of vsftpd (in `/etc/rc.d/vsftpd2`), and a symlink (`/usr/local/libexec/vsftpd2`), and I start it on boot with `vsftp2_enable="yes"` in `rc.conf`.